# Journey Builder queue SMS Messages after Blackout period

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, sms

Is there any way to queue SMS messages in Journey Builder after the [blackout period](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_send_blackouts.htm&type=5) has ended?

The only way I can think of is

1. to run a SQL query to flip a boolean flag before the blackout time and
2. update another column with the date/time when the blackout is over.
3. Then use a `Decision Split` to evaluate that flag and
4. finally a `Wait Until` activity to send the SMS message when the blackout is over.

Are there any other alternatives? `RaiseError` or Exclusion Scripts aren't available in MobileConnect and won't queue messages.

Comment: How would you join your 'controller' data extension to your data model in order to filter based on the blackout boolean? I'm only able to evaluate journey or contact data in a decision split - this wouldn't be either.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use journey or contact data? The query can update the journey DE or DE added to the Contact Data (preferred). If you go with the former, you'd have to add them to the Contact Data regardless since JB takes a snapshot of the data at entry.

Comment: are you flipping a boolean flag on all contact records in your sendable data extension?  My journey has an API entry point so records can be added to the sendable data extension and sent out at any time of day.  I'm not clear on how I'd 'catch' new records before they send out to update the boolean (blackout = true).

Comment: I had a second DE as Contact Data with the same primary key as the SubscriberKey. The data was queried from that entry DE and into this lookup DE. The Wait Until and Boolean fields lived in this lookup DE.

Comment: ah - so you had to set the black-out for each subscriber. My process includes API initiation of SMS send with new subscribers being added via these API requests.  I wouldn't be able to pre-set any black-out logic at the subscriber level.

Comment: You can try the Wait Until Event activity: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_wait_until_api_event.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to test my own solution and it worked properly. The only thing I would add is that I added another query after a Wait period of 12 hours (or however long the blackout period is) and flipped the boolean flags back to indicate the blackout time is over. Also in the query, I cleared the date/time column if the blackout flag is `false`.